# r legend trouble , how to change the text size in legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I think cex doesn't work. Cex will change the whole scale of the legend. But I just want to enlarge the text size. any command will help?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes!, set `pt.cex = 1` and change `cex` as you want as in:

```
plot(c(1,1))
legend("topleft", "Legend", cex=1.3, pch=1, pt.cex = 1)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can set the cex for the points separately from the rest of the legend.  This would still make the box small, though. A more specific example of what you're trying to do might help.  However, see if this solves your problem:

```
plot(rnorm(10))
legend("top", legend="test", pch=21) #everything is normal sized (cex=1 default from par())
legend("topleft", legend="test", pch=21, cex=0.5) #everything is small
legend("topright", legend="test", pch=21, pt.cex=1, cex=0.5) #the point is normal, but the rest is small
```

Best of luck :)